# How to test a linear regression against a NULL expectation?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, linear-model

I need to test if `y1` (in blue) and `y2` (in green) are significantly different from an estimated null `NULL.y` (orange) in this simple example here?

If the intercept is different, one way I know to test against the null is `mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + 1, data =  df)` if say you are testing if it's significantly different from 1.

Here, I am testing if values above the line NULL.y is significantly different. My guess is that `y2` will be but perhaps not `y1`.

Question: How do I compare the data with the null?

```
set.seed(111)
library(truncnorm)
x <- rtruncnorm(n = 288, a = 0, b = 10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
y1 <- -0.02 * x + 1
y2 <- -7 * x + 28
NULL.y <- -7.82 * x + 25
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, NULL.y)

mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x, data =  df)
summary(mod1)

mod1 <- lm(y2 ~ x, data =  df)
summary(mod1)

df <- gather(df, key ="y.key", value = "y.vals", y1, y2, NULL.y)
df$y.key <- as.factor(df$y.key)

ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y.vals, color = y.key), data = df) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

EDIT: For those interested in what the actual plots are--

`y1` and `y2` are the index of mean crowding of the patch (J) = `(Variance/(mean)^2) - (1/mean)`

where variance is the variance in the abundance of #trees in a patch and mean is the mean abundance of the trees.

The x-axis `x` is the mean number of trees.

Since Y is calculated from X, I calculated the null by shuffling X from the original sample, calculate Y, the slope between them. Repeat 1000 times. Find the average slope. Use the equation of the slope to calculate `NULL.y` from the original x value.

The `NULL.y` turns out to be a negative correlation. Now, I want to test if the slope for`yi` are different from the null.

In my study I actually have two nulls one corresponding to y1 and another to y2. For simplicity here, I just represented it as one null.

Comment: What are $y_1$ and $y_2$? What is the $y_{null}?$

Comment: @Dave have edited the answer for clarity on what is yi and ynull. TLDR; Yi is a function of X, hence related. I shuffled X and recalculated Y to estimate the null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since Y is calculated from X, I calculated the null by shuffling X
> from the original sample, calculate Y, the slope between them. Repeat
> 1000 times. Find the average slope. Use the equation of the slope to
> calculate `NULL.y` from the original x value.
>
> The `NULL.y` turns out to be a negative correlation. Now, I want to
> test if the slope for`yi` are different from the null.

So you attempted to run a permutation test. What you did incorrectly however was averaging the slopes. Instead, to run a permutation test you would shuffle the $X$ values, calculate the slope for the $(y, X_\text{shuffled})$ and calculate the test statistic between the slope calculated on the raw data vs shuffled data, for example $\mathbf{1}\big(\hat{\beta}_0^\text{raw} > \hat{\beta}_0^\text{shuffled}\big)$ (this will differ, depending on your hypothesis), and repeat it many times. The fraction of the cases where the condition is met would be your $p$-value.

Comment: Thanks!  I attempted some such analysis but with correlation and not slope. I guess I am not 100% certain how to compare the raw with the shuffled. I was wondering if you have any ideas?stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579545/…

Comment: @Biotechgeek the link doesn’t work. The comparison can be either `>` or `<`, or `abs() > ` where you basically count how often it is true.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579545/how-to-calculate-p-value-from-the-expected-correlation-coefficient-using-randomi

Comment: I have linked it in the comments.

Comment: @Biotechgeek it seems like you've already got an answer. I agree with the answer: its not clear what are you trying to do with the code, but it is not a $p$-value.