# How to calculate p-value from the expected correlation coefficient using randomisation in R?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, permutation-test, randomized-tests

Here, I want to estimate the p-value using randomization. Tests of correlations involving patterns like Y (a function of X) vs. X involve a shared term and the X term. Here I want to randomize (999 times) the non­shared variable while keeping the shared variable constant (e.g. I randomly shuffled X, not Y). Then I estimate the expected correlation, E(r) as the average of these randomizations. The P­-value associated with this more conservative test required tallying the number of randomizations, `rrand,j` producing a difference from the expected correlation, `|rrand,j - E(r)|` that is larger in magnitude than the difference between the observed correlation and the expected correlation, `|robs,j - E(r)|`

```
##DATA FRAME
set.seed(111)
library(truncnorm)
x <- rtruncnorm(n = 288,a = 0,b = 10,mean = 5,sd = 2)
v <- rtruncnorm(n = 288,a = 0,b = 10,mean = 5,sd = 2)
y <- ((v/x^2) - (1/x))
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 72)

df <- data.frame(v,x,y,sp)


##EXPECTED CORRELATION FUNCTION
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# function to estimate model coefficients
f <- function(x,v) {x.sample <- sample(x, length(x), replace=T)
y.sample <- (v/x.sample^2) - (1/x.sample)
per <- cor(y.sample, x.sample)}


# 999 models for each species
result = rbindlist(
  lapply(1:999, \(i) df[,.(est = f(x,v)), sp][, i:=i])
)

#MEAN EXPECTED CORRELATION
result.mean.exp.cor <-
  result %>% 
  group_by(sp)%>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean.expected.cor = mean(est))

#TESTING IF R.RAND - E(R) is greater than 0
rrand.exp <- dplyr::left_join(result,result.mean.exp.cor,by = 'sp')
rrand.exp$count <- ifelse(rrand.exp$est > rrand.exp$mean.expected.cor, 1,0)

#TALLYING THE CASES WHERE R.RAND - E(R) is greater than 0
rrand.exp.pval <-
  rrand.exp %>% 
  group_by(sp)%>% 
  dplyr::summarise(pvals = mean(count))
```

I understand how to find the `|rrand,j - E(r)|`.I thought that this in itself is the p-value. I don't understand how or why I need to calculate "that is larger in magnitude than the difference between the observed correlation and the expected correlation, `|robs,j - E(r)|`" Wouldn't this be a single number (for each species)? Am I missing something?

I also don't understand how to calculate `|robs,j - E(r)|` and compare it to  `|rrand,j - E(r)|`. In this problem, I don't even know where to start because I am comparing 999 values of `|robs,j - E(r)|` against one of `|rrand,j - E(r)|`

For all those asking: I'm trying to avoid spurious correlation issues. More reading at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00317404 Jackson and Somers(1991).

Thanks everyone. I was making a silly error on how I was thinking about this problem. I figured it out!

Comment: @ChristianHennig Here the y-axis is dependent on X where `Y = ((variance of sample)/mean of sample^2 )- (1/mean)` I am shuffling X and recalculating Y, then finding their expected E(r). I think I am finding in general negative correlations no zero..

Comment: But what is your null hypothesis then?

Comment: The definition of $Y$ in your comment seems to differ from what $y$ is in your code (involving $v$).

Comment: @ChristianHennig I am trying to calculate the null through this randomization/ shuffling method. The method I am trying to follow is derived from an appendix of a paper

Comment: If you want to run a proper significance test, you need to specify the $H_0$ before data. A valid null hypothesis can't be computed from the data. By the way, why are you interested in testing a null hypothesis that you don't even know before having computed the permutations? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Ah I see. Don't worry about the comment. I was trying to get you a sense of what v and m stood for in case you were interested. Here, each v and m are calculated from else where that we needn't worry bout

Comment: OK, fair enough. I don't really get my head around why they are interested in this specific null hypothesis (which may have to do with lack of subject matter expertise, but it may well also mean that the null hypothesis doesn't exactly mean what they think it means). I can see how they think it's well defined, and it's involved enough that I can't say straight away that it must be wrong, but it looks fishy to me.

Comment: The code isn't yours, is it? Because if you wrote the code, it'd mean that you actually understand how to compute things, which you say you don't! (If you understand the code, you should understand how it's computed.)

Comment: I believe you're confusing yourself a bit. The different species are an unnecessary complication. If you only consider a single species, you only have a single $|r_{obs}-E(r)|$, no $j$ needed there, to compare with 999 values of $|r_{rand,j}-E(r)|$.

Comment: @ChristianHennig The code actually is mine. I was trying to think through the problem on here because I was getting something messed up with the r.obs - E(r). I figured it out and seems so silly now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into whether this test problem is generally valid (see comments of the question), I can say this:

The p-value is a probability. But $|r_{rand,j}-E(r)|$ is not a probability, and neither is their mean (note that I use $j$ here for the specific permutation; therefore in my notation $r_{obs}$ has no $j$ index). Generally the p-value is the probability that under null hypothesis ($E(r)$ correlation) the correlation value is as far away (in absolute value) or farther away from the expected value $E(r)$ than what was observed.

In a permutation test, the null hypothesis is operationalised by the permutation, meaning that the probability of interest, i.e., the p-value, is the *relative frequency* of how often $|r_{rand,j}-E(r)|$ is larger than or equal to $|r_{obs}-E(r)|$.